# How are called classes generated by an ORM?

Tags: orm, model, separation-of-concerns

I have some problems with the names of the objects in an application. For example, the generated classes by any ORM (NHibernate or Entity Frameworks) are called domain objects? Entities? Model objects? Are they DAOs? What difference is there between them?

Thanks

Comment: Please revise your question. Right now it is unclear what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The classes that represent the table of your database are called domain, you usually will have one domain class for each table (except for the many to many relationship tables).

To map this domain classes to your actual database, you will (usually again) have a mapping class for each domain class, when you state the table and the different database field each domain member should be mapped to.

You now have a data access layer (DAL), to be used to select, update, insert or delete domain classes that are mapped to your database.

However, if you build an application to use your DAL, you certainly will use DTO or models. A model is an object to be displayed in an application, which is usually different than the domain. It can be a formatting of fields, a subset of data to remove pure database fields, a merge of two different domains.

Thus, your application will only manipulate DTO (or models), and when the application creates/updates/deletes a DTO, your server will manage the conversion between the DTO and the domain.

DATABASE <=> MAPPING <=> DOMAIN <=> DTO

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks a lot for your explanation. I understand that the mapping class (generated usually from an ORM) are domain classes, aren't?

Comment: Is DAL a layer that implements Delete<T> or Save<T> where T is mapping class, for example?

Comment: I like to keep my domain classes and my mapping classes separated, not sure if that's best practices though.
The DAL layer is definitely where you implement the Delete<T> or save<T>. I usually use the repository pattern to manage my DAL: [link](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article119.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, do you know where can I find an easy sample to download about this architecture? Or do you have any? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: A good c# implementation can be found here. [link]http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I found yesterday this link. Very interessant